# UITableView Vertical Scrolling Issues Inside UICollectionViewCell that Scrolls Horizontally

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to create a `UITableView` that can scroll both vertically and horizontally. The way I went about implementing this is putting a `UITableView` (scrolls up and down) inside of a `UICollectionViewCell` that I set to scroll horizontally (left and right) only. Code-wise, the solution looks pretty darn clean (and elegant in my book because of it), however, I'm experiencing some issues with vertical scrolling on the table view.

Normally, when you vertically scroll on a `UITableView`, it will keep track and remain where you left off in the scrolling -- as in the table view will not reset or move its scrolling position to a good bit above of where it left off. As you might've guessed, this is what I'm experiencing with my implementation where if I scroll to the very bottom of my table view, its scroll position gets moved to a bit above where I left off and I cannot naturally see the last entry in my table view without having to force a scroll to the bottom in order to reveal it.

Any ideas what might be causing this? I configured all of the settings for the `UITableView`, `UICollectionView` and `UICollectionViewCell` within the Interface Builder -- most important thing being I set the `UICollectionView` and its `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` scroll directions to Horizontal. I'm not sure if that's somehow being overwritten somewhere…

Answer (score -1):

[This](https://github.com/alekseyn/EasyTableView) is what you are looking for I believe.

Comment: Not quite. I'm trying to avoid subclassing all together because I believe you can achieve this solution using only the native `UITableView` and `UICollectionView` controls Apple provides out the box (which also makes it that much easier to maintain down the road). I'm very close to getting it working but its just this little quirk that's in my way

Comment: Why do you need UITableView by the way? Can't you just use UICollectionView given that it slides both ways?

Comment: You can only configure a `UICollectionView` to scroll in one direction only. It's either Vertical or Horizontal. To do what you're suggesting, I would need to use two `UICollectionViews` which doesn't make much sense to me because both `UITableView` and `UICollectionView` inherit from the same `UIScrollView` parent class. There really isn't much difference between the two aside from the various customizations `UICollectionView` provides with regards to flow and layout -- (That's why a lot of their data source methods are very similar).

Comment: If that link becomes dead the answer means nothing.